# How do I populate a select using JSON based on previous selection?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to create two select dropdowns for provinces and their cities. The idea is that I first select the province on the first dropdown, and after that, only the cities from that province will show on the second select.
I have this JSON file with the provinces and cities in Catalonia. I edited the file myself so I could have an array of all the cities of each province but I don't know if it's the best way to show the cities in the select though. Here I show you a short version of the JSON file because the original it's too big:

```
{
 "Barcelona":[
  [
   "Abrera"
  ],
  [
   "Aguilar de Segarra"
  ],
  [
   "Alella"
  ]
],
"Girona":[
 [
  "Agullana"
 ],
 [
  "Aiguaviva"
 ],
 [
  "Albanyà"
 ]
],
"Tarragona":[
 [
  "Aiguamúrcia"
 ],
 [
  "Albinyana"
 ],
 [
  "Albiol, l'"
 ]
],
"Lleida":[
 [
  "Abella de la Conca"
 ],
 [
  "Àger"
 ],
 [
  "Agramunt"
 ]
}
```

I have been able to create the first select and it shows the 4 provinces correctly with this code:

```
<select name="activity_province" class="form-select" id="activity_province">
    <option hidden selected></option>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready',function (){
            $.getJSON('/../public/utils/municipios.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $("#activity_province").append('<option name="' + key + '">' + key + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</select>
<label for="activity_province">Province</label>
```

But when I try to do the second one (cities) I get on each option of the select all the cities from each province together, separated by commas like this:
[Cities select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcQoM.png)

The code of the second select is the following:

```
<select name="activity_city" class="form-select" id="activity_city">
    <option hidden selected></option>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('ready',function (){
            $.getJSON('/../public/utils/municipios.json', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    $("#activity_city").append('<option name="' + value + '">' + value + '</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</select>
<label for="activity_city">City</label>
```

I would like to know how to iterate correctly all the cities when I have selected a province. And if you think the JSON file should be organised in a different way for easier access please let me know.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your code a bit, for testing purposes. The relevant fiddle can be [found here](https://jsfiddle.net/r6270ekm/).

The adjustments I've made refer to omitting the call to an external JSON - I've made a variable out of it, for testing and illustrative purposes. Also, if your regions and cities list is more or less constant, you can just include it as an external JS file. For example:

`<script src="/public/utils/municipios.js></script>`

And the contents of that JS file would be a JSON variable (minified or not, depending on the number of regions and cities within those regions).

The key point here is that your `#activity_province` is populated from the keys of your JSON file (or JSON variable, if you organize everything as I've suggested). You can do that right away, on `$(document).ready(...)`.

The contents of `#activity_city` appear once a region has been selected. Since the cities are the values associated with the specific region key, you would need to extract them from your JSON, clear the previous contents of `#activity_city`, and then repopulate it with whatever was listed for the selected region.

```js
var regions = {
    "Barcelona": [
        "Abrera",
        "Aguilar de Segarra",
        "Alella"
    ],
    "Girona": [
        "Agullana",
        "Aiguaviva",
        "Albanyà"
    ],
    "Tarragona": [
        "Aiguamúrcia",
        "Albinyana",
        "Albiol, l'"
    ],
    "Lleida": [
        "Abella de la Conca",
        "Àger",
        "Agramunt"
    ]
};

$(document).ready(function (){
    var province = Object.keys(regions);
    var options = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < province.length; i++) {
        options += '<option value="' + province[i] + '">' + province[i] + '</option>';
    }

    $("#activity_province").append(options);

    $("#activity_province").on("change",function() {
        var chosenProvince = $(this).val();
        var basicOption = '<option value="">Please choose a city</option>';
        var cityOptions = "";
        var cities = regions[chosenProvince];

        if(cities) {
            for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
                cityOptions += '<option value="' + cities[i] + '">' + cities[i] + '</option>';
            }
        }

        $("#activity_city").html(basicOption + cityOptions);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="activity_province">Province</label>
<select name="activity_province" class="form-select" id="activity_province">
    <option value="" selected>Please choose a province</option>
</select>

<label for="activity_city">City</label>
<select name="activity_city" class="form-select" id="activity_city">
    <option value="" selected>Please choose a city</option>
</select>
```