# Relate dropdown menu options from another dropdown menu with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, drop-down-menu

guys!

I'm working with these two dropdown menus. The first one has country options to choose. The second one, has state/province options. I have 3 countries on the first menu: Canada, Mexico, USA. What I'm trying to do is relate Canada to a list of provinces on the second menu, Mexico to a list of states and USA to a list of states as well. All the states/provinces options will be listed on the second menu but will be filtered when user chooses a country.

Can you guys help me with this code?

I need a JS code that relates my two dropdown menus.

Comment: please share what you have so far.. possibly the html dropdowns and some more details to better focus the question

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74841516/)?